# Prove that $2n\mid m$ is asymmetric

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility, relations

> Let $R$ be a relation on $\Bbb{N}$ given by $$nRm\iff2n\mid m.$$ Prove that $R$ is asymmetric.

---

I know that a symmetric relation is $\forall a,b\in A(aRb\to b\not Ra)$ i.e. $\forall a,b\in A\;\neg(aRb\wedge bRa)$.

From this, suppose that $2n\mid m$ i.e. there exists a $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $m=2kn$. **We need to prove that $n\neq2pm$, where $p\in\Bbb{Z}$ i.e. $2m\not\mid n$, right?**

If it is right then I am not able to prove it. If $m=2kn$ then $(2p)m=(2p)2kn$. What is next?

**EDIT** Since $2pm=4pkn$ we conclude that $2pm\neq n$ i.e. $2m\not\mid n$ but $2pm=4pkn$, right?

Comment: Can you prove $2n \mid m \implies n < m$ ?

Comment: @Henry please see my edit. Am I correct?

Comment: Almost. If you have $n=2pm$ you would get $4pk =1$ which can not be. So the conclusion.

Comment: @Aqua oh so you are proposing a contradiction proof. We negate the consequent and then find a contradiction. In this case the negation of the consequent is $n=2pm$, so if we plug it into the hypothesis we get $m=2k(2pm)$. If $m\neg0$ then $1=4kp$, and this cannot be possible. Contradiction. So $n\neq2pm$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with contradiction. Say exists $a,b$ such that $aRb$ and $bRa$ so $2a\mid b$ and $2b\mid a$.

Then $2a\leq b$ and $2b\leq a$ so $4a\leq a$ and hence $3a\leq 0$ a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check the edit part. Is it correct?

Comment: Can we use your (nice) argument without inequalities? I did: We will prove that $\neg(nRm\wedge mRn)$ does not hold. If $nRm$ and $mRn$ then $m=2kn$ and $n=2pm$. Then $m=2kn=2k(2pm)=2(2kp)m$. Hence $m=2hm$ i.e. $2m\mid m$, which is a contradiction. Is my reasoning right? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Answer (score 2):

My first thought at seeing this is that if $2n \mid m$ and $2m \mid n$ (if it were symmetric) then $4m \mid 2n \mid m$. So, because $\mid$ is transitive, we have $4m \mid m$. The point of this is to reduce from two variables ($m$ and $n$) to just one variable.

Now we can continue the argument: $4mk = m$ and if $m \ne 0$ then $4k = 1$, which is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check the edit part. Is it correct?

Comment: @manooooh Your edit says that $n$ (which is $2pm$) is a multiple of $4n$. This is exactly what I have (although you've swapped $m$ and $n$—which is fine, it's symmetric under the working hypothesis). But I've written it with less variables so it's easier to see what's going on

Answer (score 2):

Since we are working in $\mathbb{N}$, $2n\mid m\Rightarrow m=2nk, k\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow n<m.$

Now, if $2m\mid n$, then $n=2mr,r\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow m<n,$ so we found a contradiction.